# Is it possible to get city boundaries using Earth Engine API?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-engine

I noticed that when searching for a city or neighbourhood, the area is delimited very precisely by a red line. I have looked into Earth Engine API, but didn't find anything related to this. Is it possible to retrieve such data? Or are there other ways of finding city boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

The dataset used by Google *Earth* is proprietary and not available for general use (though [the images *produced by* Google Earth have their own terms of use](https://www.google.com/help/terms_maps/)).

Google Earth *Engine* does have a number of public vector data sets for political boundaries. Search [the data catalog](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog) for terms like "borders" or the country you're looking for data for, and you may be able to find suitable data.